# Isolating ranges in an array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, range

**Context**

A client application has a table which they can select the rows in. Each row has an associated ID. These IDs are needed if the user wants to edit the rows. The IDs must be passed through the URL's query string.

Everytime a row is selected or deselected, the creation of the string is made.

**Goal**

To avoid exceeding the maximum length of a URL's query string by isolating ranges in a string of comma separated numbers and passing the shortest query string possible.
**[5, 7, 8, 9, 77, 288]** turns into **"5:9,77,288"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I have come to, it does exactly as I wanted.

I'm always open to improvements and suggestions.

```
var prevIter = null;
var nextInRange = 0;
var maxRange = null;
var lastIndex = selectedIDs.length - 1;

selectedIDs.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if(index === 0) {
        IDs = item;
    }
    else {
        if(item === nextInRange) {
            if(index === lastIndex) {
                IDs = IDs + ":" + item;
                maxRange = null;
            }
            else {
                maxRange = item;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(maxRange == null) {
                IDs = IDs + "," + item;
            }
            else {
                IDs = IDs + ":" + maxRange + "," + item;
                maxRange = null;
            }
        }
    }
    prevIter = item;
    nextInRange = prevIter + 1;
}
```